# Cat has strange behaviours when I brush her

Tags: cats

when I brush her is that she'll do a silent meow, so it sounds like an empty meow if you get what I'm saying. It sounds like this: https://youtu.be/B3weB7V2U0g I really don't understand what this communicates.

So i need to know if its fine if I brush her?

Does she enjoy or not like the brushing?

Answer (score 1):

From the behaviour you describe, I think your cat is really enjoying the brushing. I suggest you do it more often, as it is a good bonding experience between you and your cat. Cats groom each other to strengthen their relationships, and most cats will happily be groomed by their humans. Some cats will even "groom" their humans.

If your cat didn't like the brushing, I'm sure she would be trying to get away from you.